# How to use Multi Dimensional Array

Tags: arrays, perl, multidimensional-array

I have a directory file which contains all the paths for Definition files Test FIlesand Instruction files.
Definition file looks like

```
##Definition file

Def 1 : "definition 1"

Def 2 : "definition 2"

Def 3 : "definition 3"
```

Each Instruction File contains Instruction sets like

```
##Instruction File 1
{

Instruction 1

run Def1

sleep

run def2

}
{

Instruction 2

run Def 3

sleep

run Def1

}
```

likewise multiple instruction files with multiple instruction sets

```
Test File looks like
{

run Instruction file1 Instruction 2

sleep 5

}
```

Can anyone guide me how to do this. Like how to run a specific instruction from an Instruction file

Can I use multidimensional array to do it like Storing the Commands, Instruction file and Instruction in a multidimensional array?

Comment: You should use the code formatting options and [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17296929/edit) your question so that the code is readable.

Answer (score 0):

You could use hash refs and array references.

The hash could key on the destination and then the array reference could store the array of instructions.

`$ref->{'key'} = \@array`

To open a file for reading "<"

`open FILE, "<", "filename.txt" or die $!`

To get all its lines:

`my @lines = <FILE>`

From here just split up the code based on your instructions, perhaps using a regex.

```
foreach my $line (@lines) {
    #do stuff here for the instructions
    #maybe a regex
}
```

Then iterate through and process each one..

For your test file issue you could store it associatively.

So you'd have an array of test file "command groups"

Each element could store a hash of 3 associated values

`$test[0] = { command => $command , filename => $filename, instruction => $instruction };`

From here you could access elements such as:

`$test[0]->{command}`

Comment: Can you help me with how to read and store a Test File using array reference

Comment: I added a bit of info, see if it helps and I can try to explain different parts more but I'm still not 100% on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to read the files. My main problem is how to read and store the test files. Like for the Instruction file I can store the Command(ie.run,sleep) in array[0] and value(ie.Def1 ,Def2 ,5 etc) in array[1].I am not sure how it will work for the Test File as it has three parameters Command,File name(Instruction File 1) and Instruction(Instruction 2)